# How to add multiple header include and library directories to the search path in a single gcc command?

Tags: c, gcc

How to add multiple header include and library directories to the search path in a single gcc command?

Answer (score 131, accepted):

Use multiple -I flags for the include directories and multiple -L flags for the lib directories

Comment: Does using -I/path/to/dir/ include all the header files in the sub directories  present in /path/to/dir/ also?

Answer (score 45):

You can set the `C_INCLUDE_PATH` environment variable.

```
export C_INCLUDE_PATH=.:/some/dir:/some/other/dir
```

as well as the `LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable.

Comment: This answer is pure gold!

Answer (score 24):

On Linux you need to use `-I` before each directory that you want to add.

Example:

```
user:/home/my_project$ gcc -g -Wall -I/usr/include/lib_Directory/ -I./include -c ./src/transcod.c
```

`./` means the current directory where you are running the command, in this case *my_project*;

Comment: That's an aspect of the compiler, not the operating system