# adding additional sources directory to c makefile

Tags: linux, makefile, linux-kernel

sorry if this is noob question.

In my c function, I use a macro defined in btrfs_inode.h file.
When I include the file directly to path:

```
#include "/data/kernel/linux-4.1.21-x86_64/fs/btrfs/btrfs_inode.h"
```

the project compiles with no errors, I dont want to use that direct path, I download the package kernel-source that contains this header file.
The location of the header file after installing the package is at: /usr/src/linux/fs/btrfs/

So I change the #include to :

```
#include "btrfs_inode.h"
```

and i wish to add "/usr/src/linux/fs/btrfs/" as a location that it will search for "btrfs_inode.h" and get: "/usr/src/linux/fs/btrfs/btrfs_inode.h"

I get error:
    /bin/sh: 1: /usr/src/linux/fs/btrfs/: Permission denied

I am running make as root.

**Makefile:**

```
all:: user

obj-m += my-driver.o


# Make arguments
PWD := $(shell pwd)
INCLUDE := -I/usr/include/asm/mach-default/
KDIR    := /lib/modules/$(KERNEL_HEADERS)/build;/usr/src/linux/fs/btrfs/


# Add flags to auto build
EXTRA_CFLAGS    +=-D__Linux -std=gnu99

# extra warning flags
ccflags-y := -Wall -Wextra #-pedantic
# disable some warning flags
ccflags-y += -Wno-unused-parameter
# make all warnings into errors
ccflags-y += -Werror
# increase verbosity
KBUILD_VERBOSE := 1

all::
$(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) $(INCLUDE) SUBDIRS=$(PWD) modules
```

Answer (score 1):

So first off, avoid making as root when possible.   Next, you added your directory to `KDIR`, not to `INCLUDE` (and then you pass `KDIR` to the `-C` argument of make, so you would have a line that looks like:

```
make -C /lib/modules/$(KERNEL_HEADERS)/build;/usr/src/linux/fs/btrfs/ ...
```

Notice the semicolon, which bash will interperet as the end of a command, and beginning of the next command.   So it tries to run make, and then tries to run `/usr/src/linux/fs/btrfs/`, and gives you your warning.    What you should have is something like:

```
# Make arguments
PWD := $(shell pwd)
INCLUDE := -I/usr/include/asm/mach-default/
INCLUDE += -I/usr/src/linux/fs/btrfs/
KDIR    := /lib/modules/$(KERNEL_HEADERS)/build
```

(you want a `-I` in front of the path to tell make to search for include files in that directory).

**EDIT**

You are also not passing the `-I` to your `$(CC)` or `$(CXX)` commands.   To do this, you have a couple of options, though I'll suggest the least error prone one:   First of all, you have to pass the flags to the sub make.   To do this, first add the line:

```
export INCLUDE
```

to your main makefile.  Your submake now has access to the variable `$(INCLUDE)`.   From there, if you have an explicit rule to compile the CC files, you can add `$(INCLUDE)` to the compile command.   Something like

```
%.o: %.c
     $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDE) -o $@ $<
```

or, if you are using the built-in implicit rules, simply add `$(INCLUDE)` to `CPP_FLAGS`:

```
CPP_FLAGS += $(INCLUDE)
```

(note, `CPP_FLAGS` are used by default for both c and c++ compilation).

Finally, do *not* pass `$(INCLUDE)` to your `make` command.   If you do, it tells *`make`* to look look for sub-makefiles in those directories (not `gcc`...).

Comment: I have added INCLUDE += -I/usr/src/linux/fs/btrfs/ and i get: "make -C /lib/modules/4.1.21.x86_64.1/build -I/usr/include/asm/mach-default/ -I/usr/src/linux/fs/btrfs SUBDIRS=/home/ilan/unix/v6.3/Filer/Linux modules", i included the file: #include <ctree.h> - i get compilation error ctree.h: No such file or directory, it is in the directory... If i dont use the new -I include.. and just do: #include </usr/src/linux/fs/btrfs/ctree.h> it will work.. what is wrong ?

Comment: Ahh, I overlooked the fact that you were passing `$(INCLUDE)` to `$(MAKE)` rather than to `$(CC)`.   Editing my answer to include this as well.

Answer (score 0):

From what I could understand via [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15570010/how-to-include-files-from-multiple-directories-in-c-on-linux), you can add multiple -I flags to your Makefile.