# Usage of boost in fedora

Tags: c++, boost, fedora

I really want to get in to using the boost library and I am having trouble "installing" it.

I want to be able to access the functionality by saying

```
#include <boost/signals2/signal.hpp>
```

then g++ filename.cpp.

instead of having to write

```
#include "boost/signals2/signal.hpp"
```

and have chunks of boost in my local directory.

Is there a way in which I can set up boost such that this works?
I have downloaded the boost library and extracted it to /usr/local.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I include a path to libraries in g++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6141147/how-do-i-include-a-path-to-libraries-in-g)

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way to use `boost` in `Fedora` is to simply install the `boost-devel` package, e.g.:

```
sudo dnf install boost-devel
```

It will install the boost include files in `/usr/include` and the boost library files in `/usr/lib64`.
I.e. the default include and library paths for `gcc` on `Fedora`, so `gcc`won't need the `-I` and `-L` options.

The installed version of `boost`depends on your version of `Fedora`,
see [RPM resource boost-devel](https://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=boost-devel).

Comment: I did this, now g++ filename.cpp throws a TON of undefined references. When installing boost this way what exactly do I type in the command line?

g++ -lboost filename.cpp doesnt work either, cannot find -lboost

Comment: You need to add `-l` arguments to `gcc` for the missing boost libraries. It's not as simple as just -lboost. You can ls `/usr/lib64`  to see which `libboost` files were installed.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are not passing the include directory to `g++`. Your compiler command should be:

```
g++ filename.cpp -I /path/to/boost/headers
```

Sometimes it may happen that a few headers are not found. Then you must include multiple directories where you may find all the headers. To include multiple directories see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5846804/how-to-add-multiple-header-include-and-library-directories-to-the-search-path-in) answer.

Don't forget to link the corresponding library as well! You can see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6141166/4782513) on how to do it.

Another solution would be to install boost with `brew` or a package manager at the default location which is included in `C_INCLUDE_PATH` such as `/usr/local`. However, if you intend to work with **OR** have multiple versions of boost, you quickly run into problems.

Comment: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/locale/doc/html/hello_8cpp-example.html

This file with

g++ -I/usr/local/boost/include -L/usr/local/boost/libs -lboost  myfirstboost.cpp 

throws 

boost/locale.hpp: No such file or directory
 #include <boost/locale.hpp>

Comment: Its probably because, boost can't find that header and then you have to include several directories and link several libraries. See edit to answer.